# всегда ли использовать MVCC для конкурентных транзакций?

Tags: postgresql

Приложение (PHP) по запросу покупателя выбирает наилучшие по цене варианты и выписывает счет на оплату.

В базе таблица offers:

```
id  kolvo   price   certificate
1   10      800     cert12345
2   5       300     cert23456
3   20      200     cert34567
4   15      500     cert23456
```

Приложение получает по-одиночке строки начиная с самого дешевого предложения:

```
SELECT * FROM offers WHERE kolvo>0 ORDER BY price ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0;
```

затем сверяет сертификат (отдельная операция, запрос к третьей стороне) и если сертификат устраивает, то создает позицию в формируемом счете на оплату:

```
INSERT INTO pokupki (kolvo,offer_id) VALUES (соответствующие значения);
```

И уменьшает количество товара в найденном предложении:

```
UPDATE offers SET kolvo=(новый_остаток) WHERE id=(id);
```

Затем если количество не набрано полностью или сертификат не устроил, переходит к следующей итерации (OFFSET++):

```
SELECT * FROM offers ORDER BY price ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1;
```

Естественно это все обернуто в транзакцию.

Встала задача решить вопрос с конкурентным доступом к данным в offers. Дело в том, что операция проверки сертификата занимает некоторое время, в то время как все параллельные запросы устремляются к одним и тем же строкам (из-за ORDER BY price ASC в селекте) и очень вероятно то, что одни и те же строки будут отданы множеству транзакций. Как следствие, транзакции вероятно успешно опубликуются и внесут смуту в остатки.

Почитав документацию по MVCC я усомнился, а оправдано ли использование MVCC в данной ситуации?
Дело в том, что при таком подходе каждую транзакцию создается снэпшот данных для каждой транзакции и в дальнейшем по мере выполнения либо получаем успех либо отказ, при отказе естественно пытаемся еще раз осуществить выборку. Но все тот же ORDER BY price ASC и длительное ожидание проверки сертификата могут очень осложнить этот процесс.

Подскажите пожалуйста, **возможно ли блокировать выбранную строку именно так, чтобы ее больше никто гарантированно не мог прочитать?** То есть пока идет процесс проверки сертификата она остается недоступной для чтения, и если параллельный процесс начнет выборку то он просто не увидит эту строку, а выберет следующую, которую также в свою очередь заблокирует. **И возможно ли** в таком случае после проверки сертификата (если что-то не устроило) **принудительно снять эту блокировку на чтение**, чтобы пока формируется этот инвойс параллельные процессы могли видеть эту строку, которая конкретно этому процессу не подошла?

Использую Postgres 9.2, но идет процесс создания, поэтому это не важно.

Благодарю!

Answer (score 2):

Дергать долгий внешний вызов при открытой транзакции вообще не лучшая мысль.

Эта отдельная операция на третьей стороне статична? Её можно вызывать многократно и только на своей стороне решать, оформлять ли заказ? Или она изменяет состояние этой внешней стороны, например, резервирует товар там?

Если многократный вызов допустим, то сначала выполняете обычный неблокирующий select. Затем выполняете запрос к внешней системе. Если ответ устроил, то стартуете транзакцию, выполняете запрос:

```
UPDATE offers SET kolvo=kolvo - :needCount WHERE id=:id and kolvo >= :needCount;
```

Если affected_rows равно единице, то продолжаете оформление заказа, пишете в pokupki и чего ещё надо записать сразу. Если affected_rows == 0, значит этой позиции нет в необходимом количестве. Делаете rollback и возвращаетесь к началу.

Если третья сторона не разрешает просто так дергать метод без оформления покупки, то в логику придётся вносить список ожидания подтверждений.

Добавляете таблицу, в которую будете писать лог ожиданий подтверждений с полями id bigserial, offer_id, wait_count, created_at default now(). Попозже поясню, зачем.
Сначала делаете

```
begin;
UPDATE offers SET kolvo=kolvo - :needCount WHERE id=(
    SELECT id FROM offers WHERE kolvo >= :needCount ORDER BY price ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0 FOR UPDATE;
) RETURNING *;

insert into offers_log (offer_id, wait_count) values (:offerId, :needCount) returning id;
commit;
```

Эффективно в результате вы получите выборку своего селекта. В лог копируется информация, когда, какой оффер и сколько позиций зарезервировано.

Выполняете запрос к третьей стороне. В случае получения устраивающего ответа удаляете (или помечаете выполненной) соответствующую строку в offers_log. В случае ошибки или отказа третьей стороны - выполняете

```
begin;
UPDATE offers SET kolvo=kolvo + :needCount WHERE id=:id;
delete from offers_log where id=:logId;
commit;
```

Т.е. возвращаете резерв обратно. Внимание на affected_rows удаления из лога в обоих случаях. Если там 0, значит произошла глобальная ошибка.

А теперь зачем лог нужен: если по какой-то причине скрипт упадёт, то резерв записан будет, но никогда не будет возвращён в доступные. По логу же, например, кроновая задача, может выбирать все записи из лога, превышающие какой-то интервал времени и возвращающие их к доступным.

Comment: Да вы правы, это многократный вызов каждую операцию "бронирования". На третьей стороне наши запросы ничего не изменяют, а принимаем решение уже после получения данных. Я подумаю над предложенным вами вариантов, выставлю статус попозже, спасибо!